# powershell get-process behavior different when in script

Tags: powershell

If I type this command, the results are correct:

```
Get-Process -ComputerName localhost -Id 1112,2436  
Get-Process -ComputerName localhost -Id 1112, 2436
```

Notice the space in the list in the second command.

But if I try doing this in a script, it fails:

```
$str = '1112, 2436'  
Get-Process -ComputerName localhost -Id $str
```

> Get-Process : Cannot bind parameter 'Id'. Cannot convert value "1112, 2436" to type "System.Int32". Error: "Input string was not in a correct format."

This fails too:

```
$str = '1112,2436'  
Get-Process -ComputerName localhost -Id $str
```

> Get-Process : Cannot find a process with the process identifier 11122436.

Any idea how I can pass the two ids to the command in a Powershell script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`1112, 2436` in `-Id` parameter is an array declaration, not a string. Remove the quotes:

```
$Ids = 1112, 2436 # spaces don't matter
Get-Process -ComputerName localhost -Id $Ids
```

Comment: `1112, 2436` is also an array but it is an array of _integers_ instead of strings.

Comment: The code (and this answer) is correct, but I've edited the (now confusing) variable name, as it implied that the value was still a `[String]`.